# Javascript files won't load within Visual Studio ASP.NET 2.0 pro

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

I have just loaded an existing ASP.NET project into Visual Studio 2010 that is targeted at .NET 2.0. When I attempt to run it, the first page throws an error indicating that the JQuery file was not loaded ($ is undefined). If I paste the contents of the JQuery file within  tags on the login page, everything works. This indicates to me that the JQuery file is not being loaded. I have verified that the path is correct.

This problem is not just with the JQuery file but with all JavaScript files, as far as I can tell.

I have copied this entire project directly from someone else's machine. It works perfectly on their machine. The project, on my computer, is at exactly the same path as on their machine.

If I go to IIS on my machine, and right-click on this application under Default Web Site, then choose Manage Application >> Browse, the application is displayed correctly in a browser. (I have verified that the virtual directory in IIS is pointing to my source code folder) So, it appears this issue is specific to the Visual Studio environment.

What could possibly be preventing the Javascript from loading. (the CSS files seem to be loading without error).

Thanks in advance for any debugging advice you can give me.

Comment: Can you post part of the markup that references the scripts?

Comment: When you say "preventing the javascript from loading" do you mean in the browser, or in the Visual Studio debugger, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many things wrong. Have you tried using Fiddler or FireBug and determined if the resources are requested? If they are what is the status that is being returned?

Is Visual Studio using IIS or the built-in Webserver?

Comment: Chrome developer tools also make it really easy to tell if a resource has been loaded and what its http status was for the load attempt.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. in the project's property pages, under Start Options the "Use default Web server" option is checked under "Server". Not sure what that is. [this is a brand new machine, brand new project. So everything is new to me in this environment]

Comment: Using developer tools in Chrome, I get an error that one of the Javascript files returns this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). That is not for the JQuery file, but for a different one. Then I get several "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" errors that, I think, might be just cascading errors caused by the original problem. If I just open a browser and type in http://localhost/myproject, everything works fine. So, I have a work around. It would be nice to  know why Visual Studio will not load the javascript, though. Thanks again.

Comment: It's hard to say what is causing the problem. Are you viewing the localhost/myproject in one browser and when using Visual Studio a different browser is loaded? It sounds like there maybe a syntax error . One browser throws an error the other browser works around the problem.

Comment: That appears to be the case. If I set Chrome as the default browser in Visual Studio, the page does load (at least). So, IE 9 is choking on something in the Javascript. I assume that the other developers, who do not have this issue, a) have a different browser set as their defaults or b) might be running an older version of IE. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP.